# Using saga repository for any number of sagas in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I'm using consumer sagas in MassTransit and have them set up like this:

```
services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
  {
    busConfigurator.AddSagas(assembly);
  });
```

The `assembly` parameter is referencing the assembly where all my sagas are located. What is the best way to set a saga repository for all these sagas being added?

Is it calling `SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider()` (for test) beforehand or `SetSagaRepositoryProvider()` (with the actual provider being used)? Or is there some other way to do this in a fairly generic fashion (eg. on a SagaDefinition or something) so I do not have to set it for each and every saga with the `cfg.AddSaga<MySaga, MySagaDefinition>().InMemoryRepository()` (or something else for production). This since I actually do not know exactly which sagas are injected in the assembly provided.

I could probably do some reflection, get the types and build logic around that but if there is some smart way to do this without having to go that route it'd be great.

Thanks!

I am currently, just to get things going and being able to run in tests and such a setup where the sagas are added explicitly using `cfg.AddSaga<MySaga, MySagaDefinition>().InMemoryRepository()`. But as already stated this is not the way I want to move forward but aim for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are methods to set the saga repository provider for all supported saga repositories. So the:

```cs
x.SetEntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryProvider();
```

Or whichever you are using is how you could configure it once for all sagas.

Comment: Does that call have to be before adding the sagas or can it be set any time in the dependency injection?

Comment: It can be anywhere, it isn't evaluated until the end.